# Cannot find Windows 8.1 after installing Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I'm absolutely new to Linux.

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on Windows 8.1, I chose the option to install alongside windows, but when I finished the installation I cannot find the Windows option in the boot menu.

I can find my windows partitions, but some of them (including C: drive) cannot open [fixed, I can now see all my partitions and files, including windows files].

I know that this question has been asked a lot, I found many discussions but I cannot find a way to solve the problem.

I used boot-repair but it didn't solve the problem instead I got [this log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14308764/)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no working Windows system on the disk.
When you want your Windows back - you will have to reinstall it.

As you installed Ubuntu freshly and did not configure too much,
I recommend to start over from scratch and first install Windows.

Afterwards I you should install Ubuntu again and this time choose
**Something else** from the installer instead of alongside Windows.
Select the partition you want to have Ubuntu installed manually.

I am sorry for being the harbinger of bad news another time ...

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any possibility to repair my windows instead of reinstalling it?

Comment: @EihabAhmad : I'm sorry , no, unfortunately not - you can not repair it, because Windows is not installed. :)

Comment: But I can see all my partitions and files, including windows files, I think it's boot problem

Comment: @EihabAhmad : You can try to reinstall the Windows boot loader and after that the GRUB boot loader. But I don't think this will help, as there is no Windows OS to be seen, there are only the ntfs partitions. What I would do is save the personal data to another disk, then completely wipe the disk with GParted from within the Ubuntu Live desktop environment and afterwards reinstall everything from scratch. :)

Comment: How can I install the windows boot loader? Fortunately all my files exist, I need only the boot to get my windows back :)

Comment: @EihabAhmad : It is too complex to answer this with a comment, so please ask a new question here on Ask Ubuntu - I will answer it with complete instructions ... shortly after you have posted the question. :)

Comment: I found that my Windows existed in the boot from the beginning, but it was named "Free DOS"