# How to install windows 8.1 boot loader which is damaged by ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my Windows 8.1, I chose install alongside my windows, but after finish installation I cannot find my windows in the boot menu, I can see all my partitions and all my files and windows directory and files, I need to know how to fix the boot so that I can run my windows?? I tried boot-repair and it gave me this url http://paste.ubuntu.com/14309615, I also tried this command "sudo update-grub" but the problem persists :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are instructions on how to reinstall the boot loaders only, they may not solve the general problem and they are given on your explicitly request deriving from your other question on this.

**Step 1** : Reinstall the Windows boot loader

Boot from the Windows installation media. On Install now screen select Repair your computer -
Choose Command prompt and execute:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

**Step 2** : Reinstall the GRUB boot loader

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media. Select Try Ubuntu without installing, on the desktop -
Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda8` = ubuntu system partition

Comment: It worked for Windows :) :) :) thank you very much, I haven't tried for Ubuntu yet

Comment: After I got my windows back, I tried to reinstall GRUB boot loader but it removed the windows boot, now I can only have one boot at a time, but not both

Comment: @EihabAhmad : There can only be one boot loader installed to the MBR. First we reinstalled the Windows boot loader to rebuild the Windows BCD store for letting you access Windows at all - then we reinstalled the GRUB boot loader which overwrites the MBR, but it detects Windows, so that you can boot Windows from the GRUB boot menu ... there should be an entry for the Windows system in the GRUB boot menu. :)

Comment: There isn't an entry for the Windows :(

Comment: @EihabAhmad : That's what I mentioned here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/715339/cannot-find-windows-8-1-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10 - you really should consider to rebuild everything from scratch - please read my comment again : save data - wipe the disk ...
Also important - you should install the recommended 64-bit version of Ubuntu 15.10 ... Download-Link -> http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso ... good luck my friend ! :)

Comment: my processor is intel core i5 64 bit, but what I understood from the download page is that the 64-bit version is for AMD processors. So I downloaded the x86 version. Should I get the 64-bit version?

Comment: @EihabAhmad : amd64 is just a misleading name - it means that this is the version for 64-bit processors, independent from the vendor AMD or intel ... so it is the absolutely right version for your computer. :)