# I want to install Ubuntu and keep my Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

yesterday I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on Windows 8.1, my BIOS was set to Legacy Boot mode like the following [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsBCu.png), in the installation process of Ubuntu I chose to install alongside my windows, but after the installation finished I couldn't find my windows in the boot menu and I spent the whole day searching until I could restore it, thanks to the help of @cl-netbox in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715470/how-to-install-windows-8-1-boot-loader-which-is-damaged-by-ubuntu).
Now I intend to install the Ubuntu again, please tell me exactly what options should I choose? 
Should I choose Legacy or UEFI Hybrid or Native? And should I choose to install alongside option or another option?
Thanks

Comment: @eihab: Could you please press the ☑ next to the most upvoted answer as the currently accepted answer is misleading and might ruin the next user that reads this Q&A...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows is installed in legacy mode - so you have to install Ubuntu in legacy mode as well.
Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select Try Ubuntu without installing.
Open GParted and format the sda8 partition with ext4 - close GParted.
Click on Install Ubuntu - when asked choose Something else.
Select sda8 for Ubuntu and set mount point / (root).

Comment: See comment below Q.

Answer (score 1):

Try [VMWare Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads).

You can download from above link, Don't confuse blab-la things.

We are now in virtual world, So forget old things enjoy with VM.

Comment: I already have Oracle VM VirtualBox, but I generally don't like virtual machines, they can be slow